# Changing the default emacs terminal escape character

Tags: emacs

I use M-x term in emacs, it brightens my day!

But,

Can I change the default terminal escape character, C-c, to something a little more convenient like C-x?

Answer (score 2):

I've been trying to figure this out for a *long* time, because term gets proper tab completion, even from subcommands, but having buffer commands (`C-x {left/right}`) change because you have a term open is annoying as heck.

This morning, I believe I achieved success. `C-x` behaves like normal. `M-x` requires a `C-x` prefix, which is still a little annoying, but a *huge* improvement nonetheless. `C-c` immediately results in `C-c` to the subshell.

Anyway, without further ado, stick this in your `.emacs`, and enjoy term mode so much more than before:

```
(defun term-use-sensible-escape-char (&rest ignored)
  (term-set-escape-char 24))
(advice-add 'term :after #'term-use-sensible-escape-char)
```

Sources:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18778/why-does-term-char-mode-use-c-c-as-its-default-escape-character

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17289/in-term-mode-how-can-i-make-line-mode-the-default

Answer (score 1):

You make like shell mode like better.  While in term mode, you can switch from *char mode* (the default) to *line mode* with `C-c C-j` (switch back to *char mode* with `C-c C-k`).  *line mode* works more like *shell mode* where `C-x` is the escape character.  As I understand it, the reason to use *term mode* is that it works more like a normal terminal than *shell mode*.  In principle you could use terminal emacs inside *term mode* and have the `C-x` escape character passed to that instance emacs.  Useful if you use *term mode* for a ssh session to another machine.

I often use *serial term mode* for serial connections and it is convient for me to change back and forth between *char mode* and *line mode* frequently.  *char mode* when I want to forget that I'm using emacs and just send all keystrokes to the machine, *line mode* when I want to do something more advanced like copy a portion of the session to another buffer.

Comment: I'll give that a run, but for now I'm happy, thank you.

Comment: Okay, not happy with that, just lost tab completion from bash.